# In a QTableView how to check if the the whole row was selected (by clicking on the horizontal header)?

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView with a model where not all the cell is selectable. I want to execute some code if the user selected the whole row by clicking on the horizontal header and not just by selecting a cell.

I looked around the QTableView selected methods and HorizontalHeader methods like:

```
horizontalHeader()->selectionModel()->hasSelection()
```

But that gives true even if only one cell was selected. I don't see how to check if the whole row is selected.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: What about `QItemSelectionModel::isRowSelected()` function?

Comment: Yep! That worked out. Thanks.